# Reflection with Typeclasses

Tags: scala, generics, reflection, typeclass

I'm writing a little registration module for some application and doing this with typeclasses. Main logic is based on Spray routing:

```
val api = post {
    path("register" / Rest) { rest =>
      rest match {
        case "user" => register[User]
        // ... other cases
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To simplify i have the following data type for User:

```
case class User(id: String, email: String)
```

And to extract entity from POST request i'm using typeclass:

```
trait EntityExtractor[T] {
  def extractFromRequest: Directive[T :: String :: HNil]
}
```

implementation for user:

```
object User {
  implicit val extractor = new EntityExtractor[User] {
    def extractFromRequest: Directive[User :: String :: HNil] =
      formFields('email, 'pass).hmap {
        case email :: pass :: HNil =>
          val id = UID.genId
          User(id, email) :: pass :: HNil
      }
  }
}
```

The problem arises in my register method which uses a typeclass directive:

```
def register[T] =
  extractEntity[T].apply { entity => // fails here
    validateEntity(entity) {
      completeRegistration(entity)
    }
  }
}

def extractEntity[T: EntityExtractor]: Directive[Entity[T] :: HNil] = {
  implicitly[EntityExtractor[T]].extractFromRequest.hmap {
    case entity :: pass :: HNil => Entity(entity, pass) :: HNil
  }
}
```

And it fail with an exception: `could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type EntityExtractor[T]`.

Is there any way to fix this with reflection (TypeTags or Manifest) **without pattern matching**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope the following somewhat contrived example will clarify the whole matter a bit.

Consider this code (which corresponds to your current one):

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    implicit val intIntable = new Intable[Int] {
      def toInt(obj: Int) = obj
    }

    println(squareAndDouble(10: Int))
  }

  // Corresponds to your register[T] function
  def squareAndDouble[T](obj: T) = {
    val d = double[T](obj)
    d*d
  }

  // Corresponds to your extractEntity[T] function
  def double[T: Intable](obj: T) = {
    implicitly[Intable[T]].toInt(obj)*2
  }
}

trait Intable[T] {
  def toInt(obj: T): Int
}
```

This code does not compile with the following error:

```
test.scala:11: error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type Intable[T]
    val d = double[T](obj)
```

Now let's rewrite it using implicit parameters (that's what the compiler do for us when it sees context bound):

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    implicit val intIntable = new Intable[Int] {
      def toInt(obj: Int) = obj
    }

    println(squareAndDouble(10: Int))
  }

  def squareAndDouble[T](obj: T) = {  
    val d = double[T](obj)
    d*d
  }


  def double[T](obj: T)(implicit intable: Intable[T]) = {
    intable.toInt(obj)*2
  }
}

trait Intable[T] {
  def toInt(obj: T): Int
}
```

This program does not compile as well:

```
test.scala:11: error: could not find implicit value for parameter intable: Intable[T]
    val d = double[T](obj)
```

And now it should be more obvious why it does not compile. It fails simply because there is no implicit value ('evidence') for `T` type parameter inside `squareAndDouble` function which is required by `square` function. Since `double` function need an evidence for its type parameter (which can be anything) the only way for this evidence to appear in scope inside `squareAndDouble` is from an implicit parameter again, but now in `squareAndDouble` function.

Basically, that means that you have to 'pass through' the evidence for your generic parameter in order to use the typeclass.

Let's fix it:

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    implicit val intIntable = new Intable[Int] {
      def toInt(obj: Int) = obj
    }

    println(squareAndDouble(10: Int))
  }

  // Added context bound here
  def squareAndDouble[T: Intable](obj: T) = {
    val d = double[T](obj)
    d*d
  }

  def double[T: Intable](obj: T) = {
    implicitly[Intable[T]].toInt(obj)*2
  }
}

trait Intable[T] {
  def toInt(obj: T): Int
}
```

Now it compiles and runs successfully:

```
% scalac test.scala
% scala Main
400
```

Another (may be more simple) way to understand the problem is as follows. Our `squareAndDouble[T]` function accepts unbounded type parameter `T`, but then it tries to call another function, `double[T: Intable]`, whose type parameter is bounded. This is not allowed: if it was legal, then it would be possible to call `squareAndDouble[T]` with any type, even with that which does not have `Intable` typeclass instance, and this would consequently break `double` function. Hence we have to add `Intable` boundary to `squareAndDouble` function too in order for it to compile: `squareAndDouble[T: Intable]`, and then it works perfectly.
This is in fact very similar to upper/lower bounds which work with class inheritance instead of implicit values.

Comment: thanks a lot, such a stupid mistake took away more then to hours =( Shame on me